# How to set ordering on hx:dataIterator (ibm-jsf)?

Tags: jsf

I can't find in the official documentation nothing about forcing ordering of the displayed elements in hx:dataIterator component.

This is my .jsp snippet:

```
<h:form id="tableForm" style="form">
  <h:panelGrid id="tableGridBooks">
    <hx:dataTableEx>
...

<hx:columnEx id="columnEx9">
    <f:facet name="header">
       <h:panelGroup styleClass="headerClass">
            <h:outputText id="text91" styleClass="outputText" value="#{msg.lblBooks}"></h:outputText>
       </h:panelGroup>
    </f:facet>
    <hx:dataIterator value="#{varwarehouse.listBooks}" var="book" id="dataIterator1">
            <h:panelGrid columns="4">
                <h:outputText id="text91" styleClass="outputText" value="#{book.bookId}"></h:outputText>
                <h:outputLink id="link91" rendered="#{not empty book.bookType}">
                    <h:outputText id="text92" value="#{msg[book.bookType.tag]}" styleClass="outputText"></h:outputText>
                    <hx:behavior event="onclick" behaviorAction="get;show;stop" id="behaviour1" 
                      targetAction="subview1:panelForm1:editBookDialog;subview1:panelForm1:editBookDialog"
                      onActionFunction="setvalue('subview1:panelForm1:newItem', 'edit'); setvalue('subview1:panelForm1:itemId', '#{book.bookId}');">
                    </hx:behavior>
                </h:outputLink>
                <h:outputLink id="link92" rendered="#{not empty book.publisherType}">
                    <h:outputText id="text93" value="#{msg[book.publisherType.tag]}" styleClass="outputText"></h:outputText>
                    <hx:behavior event="onclick" behaviorAction="get;show;stop" id="behaviour12"
                      targetAction="subview1:panelForm2:editBookDialog;subview1:panelForm2:editBookDialog"
                      onActionFunction="setvalue('subview1:panelForm2:newItem', 'edit'); setvalue('subview1:panelForm2:itemId', '#{book.bookId}');">
                    </hx:behavior>
                </h:outputLink>
               <h:outputText id="bookStatus" styleClass='#{book.bookStatus eq "AVAILABLE" ? "iconTrue" : "iconFalse"}'/>
               <h:commandLink styleClass="commandlink" rendered="#{(book.publisherType eq 'A' or book.publisherType eq 'B')}"
                              action="#{pc_PrintBook.printToPdf}" type="submit" value="#{msg.lblPDF}" immediate="true">
                  <f:param name="bookId" value="#{book.bookId}" />
                  <f:param name="warehouseId" value="#{varwarehouse.warehouseId}" />    
               </h:commandLink>                                                                                         
             </h:panelGrid>
    </hx:dataIterator>
</hx:columnEx>
...  
   </hx:dataTableEx>
  </h:panelGrid>
 </h:form>
```

On the business logic side the function that retrives the list of books (in the jsp above: varwarehouse.listBooks) has set the ordering by book created date descending and bookId ascending.
But, when the page gets rendered list of book items in the specific warehouse is not ordered correctly by the bookId (it should be ascending, but for some warehouses it is descending and for others is ascending).
So, since I have the correct ordering set/generated

```
(ORDER BY warehouse.created_date DESC, book.book_id ASC)
```

, I assume that the problem is hx:dataIterator component.
I didn't manage to find anywhere how could be possible to force somekind of ordering of items on that component?
I was naive and thought it will preserve the ordering of items whihch is present in the book list (java.lang.List).

Please, anykind of help is very much appreciated.
I hope someone knows the answer or maybe sees something I'm missing from the jsp above.

Thank you in advance,
Best regards,
mismas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys,
it took a while to notice that the problem was not in the jsf, but in using java Set interface which hasn't any guarantees on ordering :D.
The solution was to order it with Collections.sort ...
Tnx anyway :)